# LibreOffice Calc not offering full CSV export options

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet open in LibreOffice Calc (5.1.6.2).  I would like to save it as a CSV using pipe delimiters.  I have done this before, but I can't figure out how.

Following the instructions at https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Importing_and_Exporting_CSV_Files:

From the menu, I select 'File' > 'Save as'.
This opens "Save as" dialog.

In the "Save as" dialog, I change the 'File name' to a `.csv` extension and select 'Text CSV (.csv)' as the 'File type'.

I check the box for "Edit filter settings" and select "Save".

This brings up a "Confirm File Format" dialog; I choose "Use Text CSV Format" to continue.

This brings up the "Export Text File" dialog.  Here, my options for Field Delimiter are limited to the set [, ; : {Tab} {Space}].

I am absolutely certain that previous attempts to save a spreadsheet as a CSV has brought up a "large" version of the "Export File" dialog that includes the ability to choose a pipe (`|`) character as a delimiter, but now nothing I can do will produce that.

How do I access the "large" Export File dialog that lets me save a CSV file with a `|` delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Libre Office 5.2.7.2 on Debian Jessie.

1. Example worksheet

[image]

2. Save as, CSV, *check Edit filter settings*

[image]

3. Click Save.
4. In the Export Text File dialog, **type the character you want** in the Field Delimiter text box (ignore the dropdown choices), replacing whatever character is there.

[image]

5. Check the result

[image]

Comment: That works, of course.  I didn't realize I could type my own option.  I must be confused about the other dialog that I thought I remembered seeing.  Anyway, thank you!